# How do i save a generated PDF to Accessible storage?

Tags: flutter

I did generated a pdf from HTML code , using html_to_pdf pluggin ,

but it seems that it saves it in DocumentAppPath (data/user/0/com.exmpl.myapp/app_flutter/) which is not something easy to access by a user whom does not know much .

```
 Future<void> generateExampleDocument() async {
        var htmlContent = widget.htmlCont; // html Cv File's content

    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // appDocDir
    var targetPath = appDocDir.path;
    var targetFileName = "example-pdf";

    var generatedPdfFile = await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlContent(
        htmlContent, targetPath, targetFileName); // generates pdf document at the given path.
    generatedPdfFilePath = generatedPdfFile.path; // variable outside function .


  }
```

then displaying the pdf , it works fine  However as i said i want it to be saved somewhere where the user access it for example Download folder  .. so after i can simply Open it from that path outside my app .

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => PDFViewerScaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("SHOW TEST")),
                        path: generatedPdfFilePath)),
              ),
        ),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [esys_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share) package. I had same task, but I was generating pdf from the widget using [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package. So then I've add save button, wich calls share function with options to save the file on mobile or send it someone else.

```
final sharePdf = await generatedPdfFile.readAsBytes();

await Share.file(
  'PDF Document',
  'project.pdf',
  sharePdf.buffer.asUint8List(),
  '*/*',
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick info , but does this actually get permission and save it to somewhere accessible by the user  or  what ?

i've seen an example around of this after calling pdf.save(); 

~ Thanks .

Comment: you need to call pdf.save() if you are using pdf package. but as I see, html_to_pdf generates the file without calling save function

Comment: It will open the native os window different for ios and android, and ask user what to do with the file. save it or share it by messengers, email..., etc.

Comment: so i guess pdf package is the way to go  ?

Comment: the pdf package can't create pdf from html. ((